# Cursor based pagination timestamp

Tags: pagination, aerospike

I have to implement cursor-based pagination and am a bit confused on how to go about this given that the primary key of my entities is not an auto-increment, like for example Aerospike.

The most obvious alternative when comparison operator isn't available on the primary key in a distributed system where we don't use auto-increments, would be the use of a timestamp. But how reliable is this?

That is, two users may make an upload at exactly the same time, which basically screws up the logic behind cursor based pagination.
For example, give me the next 10 items as from a certain timestamp that was sent as cursor for fetching the next results. When this timestamp has two posts, 1 post may be dropped and neglected if it didn't fit in the previous requested count range (e.g. 10 posts of which the duplicate post would be at location 11).

How do you circumvent this problem?
The most obvious way would be to have a secondary field next to a timestamp with additional counter when a timestamp already exists, and handle the additional logic at application level, but all of this seems to add a lot of bloat.

Any insight highly appreciated!

Comment: Cursor based pagination of what? What exactly is the query?  What's missing here is a description of the data model, and you're coming at this from a very SQL oriented modeling approach, where everything is a query that returns multiple rows.  I'm asking for you to add this, because the solution is tied to the model. In Piyush's example below all timeseries events are collected in a map in a single row (record), something you can't do in an ER-diagram, but Aerospike does have complex data types like List and Map.

Comment: @RonenBotzer Rather than repeating it, the following link describes the process I need to implement: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines.html This seems easy to implement when having incremental id's, but seems hard otherwise.

Comment: This is a public forum, and the idea is for your question, and the answers you get, to be useful to others later on. Please edit your question to provide details about the data model of the problem, and include that link in the body.  I'd be happy to help if the question is clear.

Comment: The problem I have is that pagination is too generic of a term. Roughly, there could be two problems. (1) How do you paginate through the results of a scan or query that returns multiple records (rows), such as "all the tweets (regardless of user) between two points in time". (2) How do you paginate through data that is tightly associated with a single record, such as "all the tweets of a specific user". Piyush gave an example of the second problem.  I'd like to know what you're trying to do, specifically.

Comment: The question is how reliable timestamps are for cursor-based pagination (i.e. using the timestamp as a cursor). Since autoincrements cannot be reliably used in distributed systems (AS doesn't provide them), it cannot be used as cursor. For my use case, having double values for the same timestamp aren't really much of an issue, so this will work for me. I've been looking for some time, but imo, there isn't a clear alternative to using timestamps.

Comment: If we're going that generic, and assuming we're talking about events for a specific user, you could use a Map whose key is a millisecond. If that is fine-grained enough (very unlikely a human tweets twice in the same second even), it allows you to easily paginate by getting all the events between two timestamps using atomic Map operations. If key collisions remain likely in your use case, you can use a List to contain the events, and paginate by their index, assuming that post 2 is appended after post 1. List has similar atomic get operations to Map.

Comment: @RonenBotzer Thanks that's what I was thinking. Indeed, I wasn't looking for a technical implementation, it was more on the conceptual level that I was trying to find a good solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183907/discussion-between-ronen-botzer-and-trace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that Twitter uses an RDBMS auto-increment row ID for this. There are services like ZooKeeper, external to the database, with which to implement a global sequence ID. Still, you may not want to have a global sequence ID, because if everyone has to ask for a sequence from the same source you're forcing everything to serialize, defeating the whole concept of distributed processing.

Time is a natural way to sequence operations, but you need to actually agree on what the time is. If different writers talk to a service that acts as a 'wall clock' they can more or less agree on time. Like you said, you don't need nanosecond precision here.  A [Map](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) that has millisecond timestamps as its map-keys would allow you to do operations such as:

- Get a specific number of elements starting at a specified timestamp, even if there is no such map-key, using [`get_by_key_rel_index_range()`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map-ops.html#getByKeyRelIndexRange).
- Get all the elements in the interval between two timestamps, using [`get_by_key_interval()`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map-ops.html#getByKeyInterval).

To model a user's tweets you could have their IDs stored in such a Map, with the record's key being the user ID.

To model a user's timeline you could have user-timeline records (keyed by user ID) with an [ordered List](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html) containing `[timestamp, tweet ID, .., ..]` as elements. This would allow for elements with the same timestamp to exist side by side (where a map can't have two elements with the exact same key).

The useful List operations in this case are:

- Get a specific number of elements starting at a element nearest to a specified timestamp, using [`get_by_value_rel_rank_range()`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list-ops.html#getByValueRelRankRange)
- Get all the elements in the interval between two timestamps, using [`get_by_value_interavl`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list-ops.html#getByValueInterval).

See [Element Ordering and Comparison](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-ordering.html#comparison).

I have examples for how List and Map operations can be used to model different things here: [rbotzer/aerospike-cdt-examples](https://github.com/rbotzer/aerospike-cdt-examples).

Comment: Sorry, I read your reply in the chat only later. Appreciation for your answer and efforts. Yes, considering that it concerns a timeline feed, it doesn't matter to have a few posts on the same time, or even that the time slightly deviates.

Answer (score 2):

Use Capped Lists or Capped Maps as your data bin.

Capped Map Code Snippet or a variation thereof - retains last 10 updates:

```
public class CappedMap {
    public static int insert(AerospikeClient client, int i) {
        Key key = new Key("test", "testMap", "user1");
            MapPolicy mPolicy = new MapPolicy();    
                int retVal=0;
                try {
                client.operate(null, key, 
                        MapOperation.removeByIndexRange("myMap",-10,10,MapReturnType.INVERTED), 
                        // INVERTED introduced in server version 3.16.0.1
                        MapOperation.put(mPolicy, "myMap", Value.get(i), 
                        Value.get("A quick brown fox jumps right over a lazy dog") ));
                 } 
                 catch (AerospikeException e) {
                   System.out.println("Error Code: "+e.getResultCode());

             }  
                 return i;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("127.0.0.1", 3000);
                int retVal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 123; i++) {
                  System.out.println("Inserting k = "+i);
                  i = insert(client, i);
        }
        client.close();
    }
}
```